# Why does boost::factory fail for class with by-value constructor parameter?

Tags: c++, boost

I am having problems using boost::factory for a class that has a constructor with a by-value parameter. The code works if the constructor has a by-reference parameter.

Here is some code that works:

```
struct B {
  virtual ~B() {}
  virtual void work() = 0;
};

struct D : public B {
  D(int& a) : val(a) { }
  void work() { std::cout << val << std::endl; } 
  int val;
};

boost::function< B* (int&) > creator = boost::factory< D* >();
```

If I change this code so that the D constructor requires an int rather than an int&:

```
struct D : public B {
  D(int a) : val(a) { }
  void work() { std::cout << val << std::endl; } 
  int val;
};

boost::function< B* (int) > creator = boost::factory< D* >();
```

I get a compilation error:

```
boost/function/function_template.hpp:138:18: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'boost::factory<D *, void,
  boost::factory_alloc_propagation::factory_alloc_for_pointee_and_deleter>'
      return (*f)(BOOST_FUNCTION_ARGS);
. . .
boost/functional/factory.hpp:155:24: note: candidate function [with T0 = int] not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument
inline result_type operator()(BOOST_PP_ENUM_BINARY_PARAMS(N,T,& a)) const
. . .
```

Why is it not possible to create a D-factory when D:s constructor has a non-reference parameter?

I am using clang version 3.9.1 and BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_64".

Comment: Why not use a C++ lambda, you can store it in an `std::function` if you need to pass it about.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!